# How to get the toolbar back in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

By mistake I removed the toolbar in Android Studio IDE. How can I get it back.

Note: I am not talking about toolbar in android app

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Select View->
Click on Toolbars

Comment: On AndroidStudio 4.0
View -> Appearance -> Click on Toolbars

Comment: Haha, unbelievable, but new Android Studio manage to hide emulator from me... shame on me!

Comment: This is no longer the "right answer" because it was changed in later versions of Android Studio.

Answer (score 77):

If your Main Menu toolbar is hidden you can get it back by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + N` (or double tap `Shift` on Android Studio 4.x) and search for the `View | Appearance: Main Menu` Action. Toggle to `ON` to enable the menu again:

[image: main menu action]

Comment: The newer version (at least 4.x version) use different trigger shortcuts (double tap on shift key) instead of the original "Ctrl + Shift + N" combination;

Answer (score 42):

The simple way:

If you have accidentally hidden your Main menubar:

1. Double tap on `Shift` on your keyboard.
2. On the popped up window click on `Actions`  and type `mainmenu`.
3. A toggle button labelled " view appearence : Main Menu - OFF" will appear.
4. Click on toogle `OFF` to make it `ON`.

Now, the Main Menu is shown. very simple!

Answer (score 7):

For the version of 3.6.1,

It is actually in View > Appearance > Tool Window Bars.

Make sure it is ticked.

Answer (score 5):

This's the way easy and simple:

- Click on Search Everywhere icon.
- Type "Main Menu" (or anything you want to find: status bar, navigation bar, tool bar ...).
- Click on Status Button to enable ON mode for it.

Done!!!

Preview:

[image: Srr, my account be limited by SOF rule for newbie. You can click on link to see image]

Answer (score 4):

It is frustrating when you accidentally hide toolbars & even when the main menubar is also hidden, it is difficult to get back because the View tab is also hidden after the main menubar.

So what to do?

1. Press `Alt+CTRL+S` - this will open all `settings`.
2. In settings, that go to `keymaps`.
3. Find `Main Menu-> View-> Toggle the main menu`.
4. Select it and assign any shortcut you like after clicking the little pencil icon on top.
5. Close settings and press your shortcuts, - main menu opens.

You can similarity assign to Main `Menu-> View-> Toolbar` and show toolbar again on Android studio IDE. Alternatively, after the main menu opened, click `VIEW-> Toolbar` tab.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Linux and the Main menu disappeared after updating AS, and you can't find it in the `View | Appearance` as suggested in the other answers, then it's probably because of an experimental `Linux native menu` flag got enabled.

Double tap `Shift` (or do `Ctrl + Shift + A`), to get the window to type in what action are you looking for, and type `Experimental features`. Then find `linux.native.menu` and uncheck it. Then restart AS.

See here for more info https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/linux-native-menu.html#disable-linux-native-menu

Comment: THIS IS the answer for the linux users :D

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of Android Studio, the option was moved:

Older versions:
View > Toolbars

Newer versions:
View > Appearence > Toolbars

I have the version 3.6.1 and for me it is in the second case now.

Answer (score 2):

> If you hide your Main menubar accidentally, follow these steps to show
> it again

```
Pic 1:
```

[image]

```
Pic 2:
```

[image]

In `Pic 1:` The Main menubar is shown but in `Pic 2`: the Main menubar is gone.

*Step 1:*  To solve this press `Ctrl +  Alt + S`  from your keyboard, the `Settings` menu will appear. From the left panel select `Keymap` and from the right panel select `Main menu`

[image]

*Step 2:* Now `Right-click` on the `Main menu`, you will find three options `Add Keyboard Shortcut`, `Add Mouse Shortcut` and `Add Abbreviation`. Select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`

Keyboard Shortcut dialog box will appear. Select any key (`In my case its M`)

[image]

Now press the OK button, and once again OK to close the Settings dialog box.

*Step 3:* Now press the shortcut key `(In my case its M`) and you will see a popup Main menu

[image]

*Step 4:* Click on `View -> Appearance -> Main menu`

[image]

Finally, you will see your Main menu again :)

Step 5:

> Remove the shortcut key

To remove the Shortcut Key, press (`Ctrl + Alt + S`) key -> Keymap -> Main menu

Right-click on the `Main` menu, Select `Remove` -> Hit Apply, then OK button

Answer (score 2):

It is actually in View > Appearance > Tool Window Bars.

Make sure it is ticked.[image: Android Studio Menu showing View > Appearance > Tool Window Bars]

Answer (score 0):

If you have hidden your Main menu bar:

Follow the below steps:

1. Click on **Main Menu** -> **View**
2. on **View** -> Click on **Tool Windows**
3. In **Tool Windows** select the **project** or if you required any other menu you can add

Now, the Main Menu is shown. very simple!